# Passing string with special character to another page using Query string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code on on the asp page with the following commandargument:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("fldDispatchNo")+","+Eval("UniqueKey") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

The **uniquekey** in the commandargument is generated using GUID.
This is the code i have in onclick event:

```
protected void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton b = (LinkButton)sender;
        string arguments = b.CommandArgument;
        string[] args = arguments.Split(',');

        string id = args[0].ToString();
        string code = args[1].ToString();


        //int ID = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument[1].ToString());
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"700px\" height=\"500px\">";
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
        embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
        embed += "</object>";
        ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Code="), code);

        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();


        string IDE = ID.ToString();
        showdetailsonpopup(IDE);


    }
```

For now i just want to pass the code(GUID generated code) to another page. In the FileCS.ashx page, i have the following code:

```
public class FileCS : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string code = context.Request.QueryString["Code"];

        DataTable file = GetAFile(code);
```

I want to fetch data using the "code" from the database. But i get error in the FileCS.ashx saying that

> "Object reference not set to instance of the object".

The sample GUID code that I am passing is "57536028-38d0-40aa-a035-b36d8e925e81" .

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Where do you get Object reference not set to instance of the object?

Comment: I get the error at this line "string code = context.Request.QueryString["Code"];"...in the FileCS.ashx page

Answer (score 0):

You need to [URLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the value:

```
ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Code="), HTTPUtility.UrlEncode(code));
```

I also suspect there are other issues in the `GetFile()` method.

Comment: Thanks Joel, solved it. There was some issue with GetFile method too. Thank You